# vanishing a model in SDL 1.2

Tags: c++, sdl

How i can vanish a model or a change a background in the middle of the program.i try to disappear with
 `SDL_FreeSurface( dot );`
but i did not work.so how i can vanish a model and load another model.i try this but no success.

```
void clean_up()
{
    SDL_FreeSurface( model );
}

while( quit == false )
    {

        while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
        {

            if( event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN )
            {
                  clean_up();
            }
        }
    }
```

i think that `SDL_FreeSurface`just free the model in memory not in screen.
and hows about

Comment: You would have to remove the texture from your renderer.
SDL_FreeSurface only releases the resources for the SDL_Surface, but the texture is still valid. Perhaps you could post your rendering code?

Comment: SDL1.2 doesn't have texture type.  Depends on how you display your surface.

Answer (score 0):

SDL1.2 is outdated please use SDL2. Anyways for the solution

After you free the surface in the function, add `model = NULL;`, and blit the surface every `while` loop cycle by adding a `SDL_Flip(model)` at the end of your while loop, this will make your pointer point to nothing which will show nothing (aka vanish), but if you are literally talking about vanishing, you could reduce the alpha by 1 (or whatever your jazz is)  in a `for` loop which will make it fade out like it is vanishing,